# up and down key not firing keypress event textbox in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms

i am tryint to popup one selection box on datagridview cell keypress event .selection box popup working but up and down key not firing i want to move down and up selection box data while pressing up and down key from datagridview cell

these code am using

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dttmp = (DataGridView)sender;
        csearch = "";
        var txtbox = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (txtbox != null)
        {
            txtbox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxPart_TextChanged);
            txtbox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxPart_TextChanged);
            txtbox.Validating -= new CancelEventHandler(txtbox_Validating);
            txtbox.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(txtbox_Validating);
            txtbox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(txtbox_LostFocus);
        }
    }
 private void textBoxPart_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Up))
            {
                if (srchbox.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    int curind = srchbox.CurrentRow.Index;
                    //srchbox.Rows[curind - 1].Selected = true;
                    if (curind - 1 >= 0)
                    {
                        srchbox.CurrentCell = srchbox.Rows[curind - 1].Cells[1];
                        srchbox.Refresh();
                    }
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

}

Comment: so you need to use DataGridView.CellEnter and DataGridView.CellLeave events... why do you need this: DataGridView dttmp = (DataGridView)sender; ?.. you are also assigning the event to any textbox on the gird, you might want to identify the one you need and assign the event to that only... on cellenter assign the event, and on cellleave unassign it.. instead of e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Up) use e.KeyCode == Keys.Up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`DataGridView.CellEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellenter.aspx) event:

> Occurs when the current cell changes in the `DataGridView` control or when the control receives input focus.

or [`DataGridView.CellLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave.aspx) event

> Occurs when a cell loses input focus and is no longer the current cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keydown or keyup events instead.

[Control.KeyPress documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) states:

> The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Comment: i also tried keydown event but not working.. i will try keyup event

Comment: I was trying to do the exact same thing as the poster, and highlighting this little bit from the documentation helped me solve my problem by switching my event to a KeyUp event. Thank you, Jason!